# Как правильно писать и говорить: лежать в стационаре или лежать на стационаре?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Как правильно писать и говорить: лежать в стационаре или лежать на стационаре?

Answer (score 1):

"**На** стационаре" можно учиться, а вот лежать придется все-таки **в** стационаре (**в** больнице / **в** отделении / **в** палате).
Впрочем, можно находиться **на** стационарном лечении (здесь согласование со словом "лечение").